# I'm trying to figure out how Django function and encountered this recursion error

Tags: django, django-templates

i came across this error while separating the contents of the index.html file into base.html and head.html . i tried removing the head tags from this file and putting it in head.html but it didn't work. The contents of base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
#error in this line
    {% include 'head.html' %}
</head>
<body>
    {% include 'navbar.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
    {% include 'footer.html' %}
    {% include 'scripts.html' %}
</body>
</html>`
```

the contents of head.html are:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<title>Readit - Free Bootstrap 4 Template by Colorlib</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,      shrink-to-fit=no">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/aos.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ionicons.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flaticon.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icomoon.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">`
```

Comment: Please share file contents, so we can understand why this error occurred.

Comment: Please also show full error log.

Comment: Try removing `{% extends 'base.html' %}` located in `head.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're including `head.html` in `base.html`, but `head.html` extends `base.html`.

Remove the following line from head.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

Comment: Remove it from `head.html` not `base.html`